# .NET on Fedora Linux, Version 4

Tags: .net, linux

I'm a .NET noob so forgive me if my question is leaving anything out.

I'm trying to build a .NET application on Linux. I have dotnet version 5.0.408 installed, and have also tried this with dotnet 6. I recieve this error when trying `dotnet build linkto.csproj --runtime fedora.37-x86`

`error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.8 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks`

It doesn't seem possible to install the dotnet SDK for 4.8 on Linux, as it isn't listed as downloadable here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet

Comment: That sounds like that project depends on .net framework. Not .net core or .net 5 or newer

Comment: What project is it? Can it be easily ported over to modern .net?

Comment: @DanielA.White Porting to modern .net is one goal of my work. It's an older project that started some time ago and was developed using MonoDevelop. Now that it's unsupported, I'm working on moving the dev environment to VSCode

Comment: As others already commented, it looks like a framework lower than .net 5 that is compatible for Linux. (in other words, not yet .netCore migrated code like .netCore 2.2, 3.1 or 5 or 6). Either you may want to first migrate or change the framework type from .netFramework 4.8 to .net 5 or .net 6. If you are using any IDEs like VS, properties of the project may allow you to change the framework but i dont know the options if you are using Jetbrains Rider. install the .net 5 SDKs from [MSFT site](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks).